# What is the name for this design pattern?

Tags: delphi, design-patterns, delphi-xe2

I often find myself writing classes that are used like this:

- Create an object of the class
- Call some "Run" or "Execute" method on that object
- Destroy the object

This adds some overhead to the calling code, for example:

```
var
  Foo: TFoo;
begin
  Foo := TFoo.Create(...);
  try
    Foo.Run(...);
  finally
    Foo.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This could really be written much shorter as:

```
begin
  TFoo.Run(...);
end;
```

In this case the unit containing the `TFoo` class would look like this:

```
type
  TFoo = class
  private
    FBar: TBar;
    procedure InternalRun;
  public
    class procedure Run(ABar: TBar); static;
  end;

class procedure TFoo.Run(ABar: TBar);
var
  Foo: TFoo;
begin
  Foo := TFoo.Create;
  try
    Foo.FBar := ABar;
    Foo.InternalRun;
  finally
    Foo.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The overhead is moved from the calling code to the `TFoo` class.

What is the name of this design pattern?

Comment: What are you looking for? A widely used name? It's certainly a widely used technique. I just doubt it has a name because it is too trivial.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am looking for a good name for this pattern, I will rephrase the question accordingly.

Comment: In this scenario, why instantiate TFoo at all? Instead, why not expand TFoo.InternalRun into TFoo.Run?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError In this trivial example this would work and in that case it would be like a Singleton, but I was asking about the case where there could be multiple instances (for example in different threads).

Comment: Not really a singleton, because that implies state. There is no state here, just a parameter turned into an instance field. IMO, that should just stay a parameter. (I do realize that what you have here is a contrived example.)

Comment: This looks to me like a combination of a `creational pattern` (like say `Factory`) and a `behavioral pattern` (like for example `Strategy` or `Template`). You somehow create an instance and then somehow use its behaviour. I agree with @DavidHeffernan in that it is more of a common used technique than a pattern in itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have a quick look at the [Portland Pattern Repository](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PortlandPatternRepository), the first part of your question resembles the [MethodObject pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MethodObject) pretty close.

But since you're looking for the name of the latter bit, it's called a [class method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Class_Methods), and it's not a pattern, it's a language construct.

Comment: Maybe it's more like a FunctionObject, except that Delphi doesn't support overloading the function call operator. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FunctionObject

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to my (simple) implementation of the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: Command. I create the command with the target in the constructor and then (immediately or some time in the future) I call execute on it. Great for undo-able actions in a GUI, in which you would also add an undo method and add it to a list when the execute is complete.